# Filter javascript objects with another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have Javascript array of objets like this

```
var posts = [
 {area: 'NY', name: 'Bla', ads: true},
 {area: 'DF', name: 'SFS', ads: false},
 {area: 'TT', name: 'SDSD', ads: true},
 {area: 'SD', name: 'Engine', ads: false},
 {area: 'NSK', name: 'Toyota', ads: false},
];
```

and another filter collection like this

```
var filter = ['NY', 'SD'];
```

I am trying to filter my `posts` array with this filter

```
function filtered() {
  return posts
     .filter(function(post){
        return post.ads === true;
     })
     .filter(function(post){
        return filter.indexOf(post.area) > 0;
     })
}

console.log(filtered());
```

and this filter gives nothing, just empty array

[Please check jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dajg6ma6/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only need single [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method and the second condition should be `indexOf(post.area) > -1;`  since index starts from `0` .

```js
var posts = [
 {area: 'NY', name: 'Bla', ads: true},
 {area: 'DF', name: 'SFS', ads: false},
 {area: 'TT', name: 'SDSD', ads: true},
 {area: 'SD', name: 'Engine', ads: false},
 {area: 'NSK', name: 'Toyota', ads: false},
];
  
var filter = ['NY', 'SD'];

function filtered(p, f) {
  return p
    .filter(function(v) {
      return v.ads && f.indexOf(v.area) > -1;
    })
}

console.log(filtered(posts, filter));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical use case for `Array.prototype.filter()` and `Array.prototype.some()` combo.

```js
var posts = [
 {area: 'NY', name: 'Bla', ads: true},
 {area: 'DF', name: 'SFS', ads: false},
 {area: 'TT', name: 'SDSD', ads: true},
 {area: 'SD', name: 'Engine', ads: false},
 {area: 'NSK', name: 'Toyota', ads: false},
],
  filter = ['NY', 'SD'];
  result = posts.filter(o => filter.some(f => o.ads && f === o.area));
console.log(result);

// or with filter & includes combo

  result = posts.filter(o => o.ads &&  filter.includes(o.area));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a more generic solution with constraints for filtering.

```js
function filter(array, constraints) {
    return array.filter(function(a) {
        return Object.keys(constraints).every(function(k) {
            return typeof constraints[k] === 'function' ? constraints[k](a[k]) : a[k] === constraints[k] ;
        });
    });
}

var posts = [{ area: 'NY', name: 'Bla', ads: true }, { rea: 'DF', name: 'SFS', ads: false }, { area: 'TT', name: 'SDSD', ads: true }, { rea: 'SD', name: 'Engine', ads: false }, { area: 'NSK', ame: 'Toyota', ads: false }],
    result = filter(posts, {
        ads: true,
        area: function (v) { return ['NY', 'SD'].indexOf(v) !== -1; }
    });

console.log(result);
```