# Filter Javascript array of objects with another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have list

```
var list = [
  {name: 'Hello', ads: true, pas: ['Av', 'Sd', 'Qr']},
  {name: 'Fre', ads: false, pas: ['Sd', 'Bc']},
  {name: 'Nat', ads: false, pas: ['Bc', 'Mo', 'Rr']},
  {name: 'Bor', ads: true, pas: ['Bo', 'Be', 'De']},
  {name: 'Arg', ads: true, pas: ['Ar', 'Na', 'Br']},
];
```

and filter of array

```
var filter = [
 'Sd','Be'
];
```

I have tried with `filter` but its not filtering.

```
list
  .filter(function(ls) {
    return ls.pas
      .filter(function(p){
        return filter.indexOf(p) > -1;
      })
  })
```

My expected output

```
[
  {name: 'Hello', ads: true, pas: ['Av', 'Sd', 'Qr']},
  {name: 'Fre', ads: false, pas: ['Sd', 'Bc']},
  {name: 'Bor', ads: true, pas: ['Bo', 'Be', 'De']}
];
```

Comment: Use `$.inArray()`

Comment: i cant use jquery, its inside react, but i can use lodash, but i don't know how to use it.

Comment: why does the answer of the [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082363/filter-javascript-objects-with-another-array) of you does not work for you?

Comment: last question only got one level of filtering, this collection contains multiple levels of array to be filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any element from `pas` array of current object is inside `filter` array.

```js
var list = [
  {name: 'Hello', ads: true, pas: ['Av', 'Sd', 'Qr']},
  {name: 'Fre', ads: false, pas: ['Sd', 'Bc']},
  {name: 'Nat', ads: false, pas: ['Bc', 'Mo', 'Rr']},
  {name: 'Bor', ads: true, pas: ['Bo', 'Be', 'De']},
  {name: 'Arg', ads: true, pas: ['Ar', 'Na', 'Br']},
];

var filter = [
 'Sd','Be'
];

var result = list.filter(function(e) {
  return e.pas.some(function(a) {
    return filter.indexOf(a) != -1
  })
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using es6 it looks quite nice:

```
const list = [
   {name: 'Hello', ads: true, pas: ['Av', 'Sd', 'Qr']},
   {name: 'Fre', ads: false, pas: ['Sd', 'Bc']},
   {name: 'Nat', ads: false, pas: ['Bc', 'Mo', 'Rr']},
   {name: 'Bor', ads: true, pas: ['Bo', 'Be', 'De']},
   {name: 'Arg', ads: true, pas: ['Ar', 'Na', 'Br']},
],
filter = ['Sd','Be']

list.filter(a=>a.pas.some(a=>filter.includes(a))
```