# Filter through nested arrays and return objects with matching categories

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, next.js

I'm using react+ nextJS and grabbing static objects, "posts". The goal is to create a "related posts" component on each post which grabs three posts that contain at least one of the categories. Here's what it looks like when I run a map on AllPosts (I trimmed it down so it's easier to read):

```
const allPosts = getAllPosts(['title', 'categories'])
```

```
[{
  title: 'Black History Month: A History in Black Cinematography',
  categories: [ 'education' ]
}
{
  title: 'New Kid on the Block',
  categories: [ 'announcements', 'new hires' ]
}
{
  title: 'Olivia Boldt: Bol(d)ting Into the Bakery',
  categories: [ 'announcements', 'new hires' ]
}
{
  title: 'PDF Presets in Adobe Illustrator. Which one should you use?',
  categories: [ 'Research', 'education' ]
}
{
  title: 'Pixel Bakery does XYZ',
  categories: [ 'press & media', 'announcements' ]
}
{
  title: 'Recipe for Success: Mix Adaptability and Confidence (together, in a medium sized bowl)',
  categories: [ 'editorial', 'second cat', 'third cat' ]
}
{
  title: 'Samee Callahan: A Winding Path to Excitement',
  categories: [ 'announcements', 'new hire' ]
}
{
  title: 'Sophia Stueven’s Favorite Way to Breathe',
  categories: [ 'announcements', 'new hires' ]
}]
```

So far, I can get it to match posts that have the same [0] category, but I can't wrap my brain around how to compare all of them:

```
const allPosts = getAllPosts(['title', 'categories'])
const SearchCat = post.categories[0]
const matchingPosts = allPosts.filter((item) => item.categories[0] === SearchCat)
console.log(matchingPosts)
```

yields:

```
  [{
    title: 'An Introduction to our Technology Stack',
    categories: [ 'announcements', 'new hire' ]
  },
  {
    title: 'New Kid on the Block',
    categories: [ 'announcements', 'new hires' ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Olivia Boldt: Bol(d)ting Into the Bakery',
    categories: [ 'announcements', 'new hires' ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Samee Callahan: A Winding Path to Excitement',
    categories: [ 'announcements', 'new hire' ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Sophia Stueven’s Favorite Way to Breathe',
    categories: [ 'announcements', 'new hires' ]
  }]
```

How do I go about adding another filter layer that doesn't care about the position the category match is in and only require one of them to match?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter Javascript array of objects with another array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40085448/filter-javascript-array-of-objects-with-another-array-of-objects)

Comment: @pilchard YES! A few more questions though 1) How do I make the search ignore case sensitivity 2) How do I exclude the current post from the returned list and 3) Typescript doesn't like .some: "Property 'some' does not exist on type 'string'", how do I resolve that?

Comment: @pilchard Also, sorry for the repeat question. I wasn't sure what to even google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have some further questions so here is an example tailored to your use case.

> 1. How do I make the search ignore case sensitivity

You can map the `currentPost.categories` array to a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set) converting each category [`toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) and do the same in the `filter()` call.

```
post.categories.some(category => searchCategories.has(category.toUpperCase()));
```

> 2. How do I exclude the current post from the returned list

You can add a condition to the filter to look for the `currentPost` before looking for categories. (here using `title` but perhaps you have an `id` or other unique property you can use instead).

> 3. Typescript doesn't like .some: "Property 'some' does not exist on type 'string'"

That's because [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is an array method and it seems you are trying to call it on a string.

```js
const currentPost = {
    title: 'New Kid on the Block',
    categories: ['Announcements', 'new hires']
};

// const allPosts = getAllPosts(['title', 'categories'])
const allPosts = [{title: 'Black History Month: A History in Black Cinematography', categories: ['education']}, {title: 'New Kid on the Block', categories: ['announcements', 'New Hires']}, {title: 'Olivia Boldt: Bol(d)ting Into the Bakery', categories: ['announcements', 'New Hires']}, {title: 'PDF Presets in Adobe Illustrator. Which one should you use?', categories: ['Research', 'education']}, {title: 'Pixel Bakery does XYZ', categories: ['press & media', 'announcements']}, {title: 'Recipe for Success: Mix Adaptability and Confidence (together, in a medium sized bowl)', categories: ['editorial', 'second cat', 'third cat']}, {title: 'Samee Callahan: A Winding Path to Excitement', categories: ['announcements', 'new hire']}, {title: 'Sophia Stueven’s Favorite Way to Breathe', categories: ['announcements', 'new hires']}];

// Map the currentPost categories array to a Set for lookup in the filter
const searchCategories = new Set(currentPost.categories.map(category => category.toUpperCase()));

const matchingPosts = allPosts.filter(post => {
    // If the currently iterated post title matches the currentPost return false (filter it out);
    if (post.title === currentPost.title) {
        return false;
    }

    // Otherwise, check if the currently iterated post has some() categories in common with currentPost
    return post.categories.some(category => searchCategories.has(category.toUpperCase()));
});

console.log('Current Post:\n');
console.log(currentPost);

console.log('Matching Posts:\n');
console.log(matchingPosts);
```